# How to get onClick in React to work on a single element with multiple siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and have a problem with trying to fire an onClick event. I have the event working, when it gets clicked, the div appears and reappears. The problem that is that if I press a button for a particular item, all of the divs appear instead of the div that I just clicked the button on. How do I make it so that that the button I clicked on will only fire on that particular element.

Here is my code:

class App extends React.Component {

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userInput: '',
      getRecipe: [],
      ingredients: "none"
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: e.target.value
    })
  }
  

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const getData = () => {
      fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state.userInput}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}&from=0&to=18`)
        .then(res => {
          return res.json()
        }).then(data => {
          this.setState({
            getRecipe: data.hits
          })
        })
    }
    getData()
  }
// this is where the button logic comes in
  getIngredients = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (this.state.ingredients === 'none') {
      this.setState({
        ingredients: "block"
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ingredients: "none"
      })
    }
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div className="recipes">
        <Nav changed={this.handleChange} submit={this.handleSubmit} />
        <Content
          userInput={this.state.userInput}
          recipe={this.state.getRecipe}
          getIngredients={this.getIngredients}
          ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Content = ({ userInput, recipe, getIngredients, ingredients }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="userinputtitle"> {userInput} </h2>
            <div className="containrecipes">
                {recipe.map(rec => {
                    return (
                        <div key={rec.recipe.label} className="getrecipes">
                            <h1 className="recipetitle" key={rec.recipe.label}>{rec.recipe.label.toUpperCase()}</h1>
                            <img src={rec.recipe.image}></img>
                            <h4 className="health"> Health Labels: {rec.recipe.healthLabels.join(', ')}</h4>
                            <h4 > Diet Label: {rec.recipe.dietLabels}</h4>
                            <h4 > Calories: {Math.floor(rec.recipe.calories)}</h4>
                            <h4 className="cautions"> Cautions: {rec.recipe.cautions}</h4>
                            <div>
                                <h4>{rec.recipe.digest[0].label + ":" + " " + Math.floor(rec.recipe.digest[0].total) + "g"}</h4>
                                <h4>{rec.recipe.digest[1].label + ":" + " " + Math.floor(rec.recipe.digest[1].total) + "g"}</h4>
                                <h4>{rec.recipe.digest[2].label + ":" + " " + Math.floor(rec.recipe.digest[2].total) + "g"}</h4>
                            </div>
// the button is clicked here, yet all div fire at the same time
                            <button onClick={getIngredients} className="getingredients">Ingredients</button>
                            {rec.recipe.ingredients.map(i => {
                                return (
                                    <div style={{ display: ingredients }} className="containingredients">
                                        < ul className="ingredients">
                                            <li className="ingredient">{i.text}</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                )

                            })}
                        </div>

                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: Either add a property to the mapped data or keep a separate data structure to hold a "toggled" state for the specific element you want to toggle. Use an element ID to toggle the value. Update the `getIngredients` callback to consume this unique ID. Try this and update question if your stuck or have issues implementing.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by adding a property to the mapped data.

Comment: I meant you can augment your data and add a property for each element to toggle. I answered below with just using a extra data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `getIngredients` to consume also a recipe ID and save that in state instead.

## Toggle single recipe ingredient

```
this.state = {
  userInput: '',
  getRecipe: [],
  ingredientsId: null
}

...

getIngredients = recipeId => e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ingredientsId: prevState.ingredientsId ? null : recipeId,
  }));
}

...

<Content
  userInput={this.state.userInput}
  recipe={this.state.getRecipe}
  getIngredients={this.getIngredients}
  ingredientsId={this.state.ingredientsId} // <-- pass id
/>
```

Conditionally set the display style in `Content`.

```
const Content = ({ userInput, recipe, getIngredients, ingredientsId }) => {

  ...

  <button
   onClick={getIngredients(recipe.id)} // <-- pass id
   className="getingredients"
  >
    Ingredients
  </button>
  <div
   style={{
     // set display style
     display: ingredientsId === recipe.id ? "block" : "none"
   }}
   className="containingredients"
  >
    <ul className="ingredients">
      <li className="ingredient">{i.text}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  ...
```

## Toggle multiple recipe ingredient

Same as above with minor changes

State is map

```
this.state = {
  userInput: '',
  getRecipe: [],
  ingredientsId: {},
}
```

Toggle id in handler

```
getIngredients = recipeId => e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ingredientsId: {
      ...prevState.ingredientsId,
      [recipeId]: !prevState.ingredientsId[recipeId]
    },
  }));
}
```

Look up recipeId in passed map

```
style={{
  // set display style
  display: ingredientsId[recipe.id] ? "block" : "none"
}}
```

Comment: where did prevstate come from

Comment: @Alanaj "state", or in this case named `prevState`, is the first argument to the `setState` updater function, part of the API. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate It's commonly referred to as a functional state update.

Comment: Hi, I've been studying your code trying to figure it out. Why does the recipeId turn into recipe.id?

Comment: @Alanaj It isn't really that one is turning into the other, but it's sort of the other way around. In this case it is assuming the `recipe` object has an `id` property and this id is what is passed to the callback `getIngredients` and saved to a local variable called `recipeId`.

Comment: that's what I figured but it doesn't have an recipe id on it, that's probably why the code isn't working. Do I use another identifier maybe?

Comment: @Alanaj Sorry for confusion. Yes, any recipe identifier that is unique among your dataset. Typically it's an id field, but it can be anything really, it just needs to be unique.

Comment: No problem, also sorry, last question. Why is it this (getIngredients = recipeId => e => ), instead of this getIngredients = (e, recipeId) ?

Comment: @Alanaj It's a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, i.e. specifically a function that takes an id and returns a function that takes an event object. It's the difference between writing `onClick={getIngredients(id)}` and `onClick={e => getIngredients(e, id)}`.

Comment: thank you so much. I studied your code and the suggestions you gave helped me. You have made me a better developer. Thank you again!

Comment: @ Drew Reese, Sorry, that was my last question because i tried the anonymous function and it didn't work but the first way did. Thank you!